# When i run auto.arima I get different values for the parameter "d" and ndiffs using x regressors

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Im new using r. Im performing a kpss test on my "y" variable and running ndiffs procedure, and in both cases get 1 for the parameter "d" , but when I run auto.arima with x regressors I get 0 for the parameter "d" -> arima(1,0,2). Maybe auto.arima check cointegration of the "y" and "x" first? Thanks for your help.

Here is my data:

y
2.444375
2.452654
2.500772
2.184615
2.407407
2.363694
2.608972
2.767053
2.784
2.663671
2.511125
2.540461
2.569797
2.54372
2.233567
2.17803
2.259178
2.323361
2.424444
2.354524
2.391378
2.603471
2.686763
2.811376
2.834395
3.033206
3.189138
3.240013
3.345841
3.399615
3.214401
3.41275
3.3034
3.595291
3.579418
3.672948
3.600389
3.449398
3.160639
3.389283
3.02439
3.350854
3.30142
3.053185
2.966381
3.135206
3.136349
3.325574
3.328895
3.498834
3.57261
3.361065
3.341208
3.084304
3.332139
3.152992
3.541742
3.402579
3.352559
3.295129
3.466762
3.796562
3.89564
4.242204
4.417671
4.510166
4.979408
4.636261
4.787234
4.517844
4.552469
4.478193
4.204625
4.120387
4.055496
3.909613
4.020283
4.215543
4.149533
3.742515
3.583553
3.652968
3.31825
3.28972

x1
7.79346
7.529054
7.198324
6.853664
6.623179
6.588312
6.685664
6.742842
6.6382
6.389427
6.115808
5.918737
5.832885
5.838153
5.909675
5.998403
6.021378
5.893726
5.628929
5.365671
5.267813
5.369108
5.550737
5.661033
5.651363
5.588613
5.569582
5.629886
5.736675
5.837155
5.883258
5.823914
5.618879
5.286827
4.910896
4.582544
4.32244
4.07034
3.743013
3.314878
2.834001
2.389747
2.054814
1.864502
1.822395
1.894742
2.014696
2.124781
2.217244
2.33357
2.52072
2.786884
3.097505
3.400743
3.653563
3.830736
3.928788
3.976288
4.028432
4.126163
4.25858
4.365297
4.384469
4.29591
4.124274
3.914298
3.70659
3.529173
3.397965
3.309213
3.234892
3.135474
2.990136
2.810962
2.640742
2.519209
2.468514
2.487364
2.562578
2.678447
2.81635
2.950987
3.059694
3.14105

x2
3.438469
3.429541
3.425114
3.429327
3.442149
3.452176
3.443765
3.407517
3.350413
3.2909
3.247644
3.224348
3.213491
3.203326
3.188661
3.167408
3.137053
3.09396
3.042543
2.998623
2.982526
3.002105
3.046648
3.093907
3.128687
3.149379
3.16585
3.186673
3.214621
3.245867
3.27377
3.290852
3.291527
3.274292
3.241789
3.198914
3.151563
3.105598
3.064539
3.027491
2.990368
2.951589
2.915814
2.891769
2.885791
2.896554
2.915825
2.935736
2.952546
2.966099
2.976254
2.983647
2.99127
3.005858
3.033343
3.075706
3.127353
3.178364
3.220777
3.255776
3.290388
3.332591
3.383335
3.438199
3.490746
3.538221
3.580741
3.618347
3.646485
3.65941
3.655832
3.643982
3.635024
3.636948
3.647817
3.662022
3.67504
3.687781
3.702058
3.717368
3.731015
3.743369
3.760409
3.790639
x2
3.438469
3.429541
3.425114
3.429327
3.442149
3.452176
3.443765
3.407517
3.350413
3.2909
3.247644
3.224348
3.213491
3.203326
3.188661
3.167408
3.137053
3.09396
3.042543
2.998623
2.982526
3.002105
3.046648
3.093907
3.128687
3.149379
3.16585
3.186673
3.214621
3.245867
3.27377
3.290852
3.291527
3.274292
3.241789
3.198914
3.151563
3.105598
3.064539
3.027491
2.990368
2.951589
2.915814
2.891769
2.885791
2.896554
2.915825
2.935736
2.952546
2.966099
2.976254
2.983647
2.99127
3.005858
3.033343
3.075706
3.127353
3.178364
3.220777
3.255776
3.290388
3.332591
3.383335
3.438199
3.490746
3.538221
3.580741
3.618347
3.646485
3.65941
3.655832
3.643982
3.635024
3.636948
3.647817
3.662022
3.67504
3.687781
3.702058
3.717368
3.731015
3.743369
3.760409
3.790639

Answer (score 1):

`auto.arima()` does not perform any tests for cointegration. It simply regresses $y$ on all covariates you specify in the `xreg` parameter, then considers the residuals. See Rob Hyndman's blog post ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) for more information.

`auto.arima()` does test these residuals for seasonality. However, note that (`?auto.arima`)

> the default method for selecting seasonal
>        differences is now based on an estimate of seasonal strength
>        ([Wang, Smith & Hyndman, 2006](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10618-005-0039-x))

So this is not, e.g., a KPSS test. Of course, different tests can yield different results, so if you perform your KPSS test on residuals from a regression, it may believe that the residuals are seasonal, whereas the test used in `auto.arima()` may differ.